# How to insert a space at the beginning and end of parentheses in VSCode?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, formatting, format

I've tried a lot of extensions, including PHP Intelephense and Space Inside Braces.
I can't get what I want.

From the following code:

```
function foo($a, $b) {
}
foo($a, $b);
```

I want this result:

```
function foo( $a, $b ) {
}
foo( $a, $b );
```

Answer (score -3):

Simple. Just `CTRL+H` (or Edit->Replace) and replace '(' with '( ' and ')' with ' )'.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's clever, but is it possible that this action happens directly when I format my code (with ALT + SHIFT + F)? Is there a way with PHP on VSCode?

Comment: @HugoDerre You could probably find a formatter that you could configure. But I bet this is the easiest option. :)